# Can a 3com AP2750 be used with a regular router?

Tags: wireless-networking

Can a 3com AP2750 be used with a regular 3rd party router? The documentation says it requires a 3com wireless switch.
I want to use it to create a wireless network from a non-wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that is a "Managed Access Point", meaning all configuration is handled centrally by the switch, so a (compatible) 3Com management switch is necessary to configure and control the AP.

From [the manual for that AP](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.rid_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.rst_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02583240-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01_ws_BI&ac.admitted=1390696455192.876444892.199480143):

> The 3Com AP2750 Managed Access Point provides IEEE 802.11a or
>   802.11b/g wireless access to the network. The access point is designed for use with a 3Com Wireless LAN Switch, and requires hardware
>   installation only. **All configuration for the access point takes place
>   on the 3Com Wireless LAN Switch**.
>   **You must have a wireless switch device to operate the access point.**